# FIB: execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn Swift and wrote a simple fib function

```
func fib(n: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    var nums = [0, 1]
    for i in 2...n {
        nums[i] = nums[i-1] + nums[i-2]
    }
    return nums[n]
}
fib(2)
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
ERROR: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code-EXC_1386_INVOP, subode=0x0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an item to the end of an array, you have to call the `append()` method.
You cannot extend the array by assigning a value to an index that is equal to the array's
count. So you should replace

```
nums[i] = nums[i-1] + nums[i-2]
```

by

```
nums.append(nums[i-1] + nums[i-2])
```

(But note that you do not really need an array to compute the Fibonacci numbers,
as it is sufficient to remember the last *two* values.)